# What is wrong in this if condition?

Tags: bash, if-statement

This is my code

```
ports="161,123"
portsArr=$(echo "${ports}" | tr "," "\n")
for port in "${portsArr[@]}"
do
    echo "${port}"

    if [ "${port}" = "161" ]; then
        echo "161";
    fi

    if [ "${port}" = "123" ]; then
        echo "123";
    fi
done
```

For some reason, the if conditions in this code is not working. Although, I'm getting expected results in the Line 5 echo command. Can somebody please explain what is wrong here?

Comment: `portsArr` is not an array. `IFS=, read -ra portsArr <<< "$ports"` might be what you wanted.

Comment: @Sandeep : Like Jetchisel said, or `portsArr=( $(tr , ' ' <<<"$ports") )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare an array, you need some `( )`:

```
portsArr=( $(echo "${ports}" | tr "," "\n") )
```

You should consider using bash's test : `[[ ]]`

```
[[
```

is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we recommend `[[`.